# Google ads iframe being blocked for home page

Tags: iframe, ads, adsense, adsense-api

I am working on my local website page for google ads: fatehjangcity.com

Ads are displayed on almost every page but problem occurs when we visit home/default/index page...

> When working on localhost: ads displayed on home page correctly

I dont know the reason why ads are being blocked or iframes are blocked in other words.....although when using commands for forcing chrome_console, ads displayed......

i.e: fatehjangcity.com/?chrome_console=1

No. of possible causes:

```
1-ad bot making problem or confused

2-publisher problem(http vs https)

3-redirect issue

4-carwler's issue(i dont think)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not a lot of details to go on but if you are putting the Adsense html inside an iFrame it won't work.

If you go to https://support.google.com/adsense and search for iFrame policy it will tell you that Adsense doesn't allow containing iFrames.